# in matlab, find 3D neighbourhood

Tags: matlab, 3d, neighbours

I have a volume (3D matrix) that has undergone a segmentation process. Most of the volume consist of NaNs (or zeros), except regions that have passed some criteria (see picture). I need to know how large each remaining segment is in number of voxels and how is their distribution on the 2D planes (xy, xz, yz). Is there anything in matlab that can help me do this in an efficient way rather than direct search? The volume can be rather large. For ex. in the attached picture there is one segment in yellowish/brownish colour of 7 voxels and extends more vertically than in xy.
Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most convenient solution is to use [REGIONPROPS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html). In your example:

```
stats = regionprops(image, 'area', 'centroid')
```

For every feature, there is an entry in the structure stats with the area (i.e. # of voxels) and the centroid.

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you are looking for is called `bwlabeln`. It allows you to find blobs in 3D space, just like `bwlabel` does in 2D. Afterwards, you can use `regionprops` to find out the properties of the data.

Taken directly from help:

> bwlabeln Label connected components in binary image.
>       L = bwlabeln(BW) returns a label matrix, L, containing labels for the
>       connected components in BW.  BW can have any dimension; L is the same
>       size as BW.  The elements of L are integer values greater than or equal
>       to 0.  The pixels labeled 0 are the background.  The pixels labeled 1
>       make up one object, the pixels labeled 2 make up a second object, and
>       so on.  The default connectivity is 8 for two dimensions, 26 for three
>       dimensions, and CONNDEF(NDIMS(BW),'maximal') for higher dimensions.

Comment: You do not need to call `bwlabeln` before calling `regionprops`.

Comment: Thanks guys. You saved me a lot of time.