# Find dimensions of object in 3D

Tags: matlab, 3d, plane

I have a irregular shaped round object(blue) in 3D that lies on a straight plane(purple). [image: 3D Object]
The object consists of a 3xn matrix which contains its x, y and z-coordinates. The plane is constructed using 2 vectors and a point it passes through.
I want to know the perimeter and cross-sectional the object encloses. I know how to obtain these dimensions in binary 2D images using the [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html/) function from the image processing toolbox, but I don't know how to do this for 3D objects. Can anybody help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: If your object is in a plane, why don't you translate this plane to the XY coordinates and do it if it was 2D? You can also create some "plane coordinates, and do it there.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Is these almost the same. Rotation and translation are mappings as well...

Comment: @patrik yes,  yes I know. They are just different ways of seeing the same problem.

Comment: `regionprops` should also work for 3d objects. see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958969/in-matlab-find-3d-neighbourhood

Comment: Thank you @AnderBiguri. I've solved the problem by creating a new 2D coordinate system. Thereafter I used `drawPolyline` to create a polyline and calculate the area using `polyarea`.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by creating a new 2D coordinate system. Thereafter I used `drawPolyline` to create a polyline and calculate the area using `polyarea`.